# How to store different types of nodes in one linked-list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to store different types of nodes in one linked-list , i built a structure

```
struct node{struct node *next};
```

and two classes ,

the first class is

```
class doc1
{
 private : int data ;
}
```

the second class is

```
class doc2
{
 private : double number ;
}
```

and a class to contain the whole list

```
class list : public doc1 ,public doc2
{
public : void add_node();
private : struct node * head = NULL ;
}
```

Actually i am asking how to make the "head" pointer point to different nodes -each node may contain an object from two different classes-.

Is template good to solve this problem ?!

Thanks .

Comment: Make two nodes.

Comment: Are `doc1` and `doc2` related somehow (common base class)? Do you need to store `doc1` and `doc2` objects in the same linked list instance, or is it OK to have a specific type of `docx` to be stored in the list?

Comment: @JakeFreeman And a 3rd one for `doc3`??

Comment: @user0042 your idea is better.

Comment: In this specific case you can just use `double` for everything because you can store an `int` in a `double`. In general you can consider a `std::variant<doc1, doc2>`.

Comment: @JakeFreeman
yes doc1 and doc2 are related to base class , let's call it father class , and i need to store doc1 and doc2 objects in the same linked list

Comment: `class list : public doc1 ,public doc2` makes no sense in C++. It means a `list` is a `doc1` and also a `doc2`. What you meant was something like "a `list` has `doc1`s and `doc2`s" which suddenly makes sense and gives you the obvious solution `class list{ std::vector<doc1> doc1s; std::vector<doc2> doc2s; };`.

Comment: @nwp
it's not true for doc1 and doc2 to inherit from base class , in this way ? 
i need to use inheritance and polymorphism not vectors

Comment: Having `doc1` and `doc2` inherit from `doc` makes some sense, although it arguably isn't great design. Having a `list` inherit from its elements makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Which version of C++ you use?

Answer (score 2):

> and a class to contain the whole list
>
> ```
> class list : public doc1 ,public doc2
> {
> public : void add_node();
> private : struct node * head = NULL ;
> }
> ```

Sorry I need to say that, but that doesn't make any sense.

Inheritance is the not the right tool [*aggregate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) something.

Your list *contains* `doc1` and `doc2` instances, but neither *is a* `doc1` or `doc2`, but *owns* these or collects *weak references*.

---

The most flexible way to do this is to provide a common (abstract) base class for the `doc` types and store a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for them in the `node` class:

```
class doc {
protected:   // make doc abstract, it can only be used with directly inheriting
    doc() {} // classes
public:
    virtual ~doc() {} // make doc polymorphic
};

class doc1 : public doc {
    // special stuff
};

class doc2 : public doc {
    // special stuff
};

struct node { 
    node *next;
    std::unique_ptr<doc> doc_data;
};
```

---

```
class list {
public: 
    list() : head(nullptr) {}
    template<tyoename T>
    void add_node(const T& data) {
         static_assert("data must derive from doc",std::is_base_of<doc,T>::value);
         node* newNode = new node(); // Note you still need to do the memory 
                                     // management for your node instances!
         newNode->doc_data = std::make_unique<T>(data); // T needs to be 
                                                        // copy constructible
         // linked list management code ...
    }
private: 
    node* head;
}
```

---

> Is template good to solve this problem ?!

As you see from my example above I used a templated `add_node()` function to make taking `doc1` or `doc2` types convenient.

A template can also help to make your whole `list` class working for arbitrary data types:

```
template<typename T>
class MyList {
public:
    // I'm using a nested node type here
    struct node {
        node* next;
        T data;
        node() : next(nullptr), data() {}
        node(const T& value): next(nullptr), data(value) {}
    };

    MyList() : head(nullptr) {}
    void add_node(const T& value) {
        node* new_node = new node(value);
        // linked list management code ...
    }
private:
    node* head;
};
```

For the above implementation you can also take advantage of `std::unique_ptr` for the contained `doc` instances and mix the types:

```
MyList<std::unique_ptr<doc>> myList;
```

That of course also works for unrelated types then like:

```
MyList<doc1> myDoc1List;
MyList<doc2> myDoc2List;
MyList<int> myInt1List;
MyList<double> myDouble1List;
```

---

The way easiest thing of course is to just use the already existing linked list implementation of the [c++ standard containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container):

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<doc>> myLinkedDocList;
```

Comment: Agreed. If you're going to stick everything in a single list, you have to think of what you want to do with them in the end. If you're checking types and acting on the type, better to have two separate lists. If, on the other hand, you work with a common interface, then you already have a base class.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax That totally depends on the use case, which wasn't disclosed by the OP so far.

Comment: Well, from a practical design standpoint, it's either one or the other (in most cases I've encountered). Anyway, what I was pointing out was that the desired usage of the list might be a good hint towards the proper solution

Comment: @ZeroUltimax Well, such comment would better apply to the question not to an answer then, no?